# Focus lost after update

Tags: javascript, jsf, jquery, primefaces

I have form with two inputs, where one value depends on another. When user change one field I need to recalculate values (this is done in setter methods) and update the form.

This is my example:

```
<h:form>
<p:inputText id="price1" value="#{bean.price1}"}">
    <p:ajax event="blur" update="@this, price2"/>
</p:inputText>
<p:inputText id="price2" value="#{bean.price2}">
    <p:ajax event="blur" update="@this, price1"/>
</p:inputText>
</h:form>
```

The problem is that after update focus is lost e.g. if user moves from price1 to price2 using Tab key.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
<h:form id="fm">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('fm:price2')).focus();
        }
    </script>
    <p:inputText id="price1" value="#{bean.price1}" >
        <p:ajax event="blur" oncomplete="test();" update="@this, price2"                listener="#{bean.hand}"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <p:inputText widgetVar="xxx" id="price2" value="#{bean.price2}">
        <p:ajax event="blur" update="@this, price1"/>
    </p:inputText>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Set `widgetVar` for your input
- For the `p:ajax`, set `oncomplete="PF('YOUR_WIDGET_VAR_NAME').jq.focus();"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#price2").focusout(function(){
    $("#price1").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying issue, which has to do with the way JSF preforms partial renders. It replaces the entire element being re-rendered, leading to the focus being lost.

The only way to tackle this is by storing the tabIndex of the focus holding element and setting the focus again after the DOM has been updated.

You can find more details regarding the solution in this blog post [JSF 2 AJAX focus issues](http://www.knitelius.com/2014/07/15/keeping-focus-on-element-with-jsf-2-ajax-render/).

Comment: References to external posts in an answer are fine IF you create a very good summary in the answer itself. If this is not possible, please state so (e.g. if the summary would become very complex).

Answer (score 0):

This helpful post shows how to set the focus in your backing bean; granted it breaks the separation between bean/ui, but it does allow you to add some logic to where you want to set focus if needed:

http://jsfcorner.blogspot.com/2015/06/focus-html-element-after-ajax-call-with.html

tldr: 
`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PrimeFaces.focus('frm:additionalInfo');");`